# Multiple Cubes separate by dimension value

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I created two cubes same structure same data source but would like to separate them out by region and country level. One cube should show UK and another should  show up Australia.

I have tried New Named Set but this method didn't work as It will not give results for region if I drag both region and country.

Also I tried to create two data source views where condition applied on dimension. but didn't work.

Please suggest

Comment: Can you please elaborate your second line, "I have tried New Named Set but this method didn't work as It will not give results for region if I drag both region and country." ?

Comment: I'm not clear why you're creating two cubes.  Are they effectively the same cube in Visual Studio?  One solution is to create one cube, create two Roles with CubeReader access, and use Dimension Security to give each role access to just UK or Australia in the Geography dimension.